# Hide element on hover of another element

Tags: html, css

I know it can be done in `JavaScript`, however I am looking for solution in `CSS`.

I have three divs.

- div#hide should be visible by default, #show should be hidden.
- When I hover on #main, #hide should hide and #show should be visible.

div#show works fine but #hide doesn't hide when #main is hovered. How can we do it in css?

```css
#show {
  display: none
}
#main:hover + #show {
  display: block
}
#main:hover + #hide {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  Hover me
</div>
<div id="show">
  Show me on hover
</div>
<div id="hide">
  Hide me on hover
</div>
```

Comment: Go look up what `+` in the selector does. While doing so, you should also find its more general counterpart.

Comment: https://fiddle.jshell.net/393wqmwp/1/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Instead of `+` you want to use `~` combinator for `hide` element because `+` selects only next-sibling

```css
#show {
  display: none
}
#main:hover + #show {
  display: block
}
#main:hover ~ #hide {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  Hover me
</div>
<div id="show">
  Show me on hover
</div>
<div id="hide">
  Hide me on hover
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to replace the `+` selector with `~` cause the `#hide` is not placed after `#main`

So your code is:

```
#show {display:none}
#main:hover + #show { display:block }
#main:hover ~ #hide { display:none }
```

Answer (score 0):

You've to use tilda '~' for this case.

The difference between + and ~ is that ~ matches all following siblings regardless of their proximity from the first element, as long as they both share the same parent.

```
    #show {display:none}
    #main:hover + #show { display:block }
    #main:hover ~ #hide { display:none }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this: "#main:hover + #show + #hide"

```
div#show {
    display:none;
}
#main:hover + #show {
    display:block 
}
#main:hover + #show + #hide {
    display:none
}
```

It's working for me.