# How do i achieve CSS Hover here?

Tags: css

I need to show a divon hover of a tag.
This is my code.

```
<div class="p-0 d-inline-block main-div" 
        [ngClass]="{
            'col-md-10': showSideBar,
            'col-md-12': !showSideBar
        }">
        <div class="nav-div d-flex justify-content-start navbar-fixed-top">
            <a style="cursor: pointer;" 
                class="user-a my-auto">
                <img class="fa-user" src="/assets/images/user.svg" width="30" alt="user">
            </a>
            <a style="cursor: pointer;" class="logout-a my-auto" (click)="logout()">
                <img src="/assets/images/logout.svg" width="30" alt="logout">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="user-details d-inline-block pull-right text-center mr-2">hello</div>
    </div>
```

I already tried answer on
[Hide element on hover of another element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41803496/hide-element-on-hover-of-another-element)

My css which is not working

```
.user-details {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.main-div .nav-div .user-a:hover + .main-div .user-details{
    visibility: visible;
}
```

If hover on user-a link, user-details should be visible!

How do i achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide element on hover of another element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41803496/hide-element-on-hover-of-another-element)

Comment: Sir, i have tried it in my css, it isnt working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code don't work because you try to use `+` that selector is for next sib.

To do what you want you have to insert the second element in the same div and use `~` selector example:

```css
.user-details {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.user-a:hover ~ .user-details{
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="p-0 d-inline-block main-div" 
        [ngClass]="{
            'col-md-10': showSideBar,
            'col-md-12': !showSideBar
        }">
        <div class="nav-div d-flex justify-content-start navbar-fixed-top">
            <a style="cursor: pointer;" 
                class="user-a my-auto">
                <img class="fa-user" src="/assets/images/user.svg" width="30" alt="user">
            </a>
            <a style="cursor: pointer;" class="logout-a my-auto" (click)="logout()">
                <img src="/assets/images/logout.svg" width="30" alt="logout">
            </a>
            <div class="user-details d-inline-block pull-right text-center mr-2">hello</div>
        </div>        
    </div>
```

Alternatively you could use `javascript`